# ORA -12154:TNS could not resolve thye connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle10g, toad

Windows 7- 64bit ;
Oracle client - 10g ;
Toad - 9.7

I recently upgraded my machine to win 7 and installed Oracle and Toad  software and dont have much knowledge about oracle and toad.

When i try to connect to my database through Toad i get the error **"ORA -12154:TNS could not resolve the connect identifier specified"**

My Path variable has C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin.
Oracle_Home is C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1 
TNS_ADMIN is C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN

Comment: Does `tnsping yourdbname` run successfully? Can you connect to the database through SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 1):

i installed toad under my c: instead of C:\Program Files (x86) which solved the issue